# I am running "Union" on two shapefile in QGIS, Its running very slow and taking weeks to process 1 lac records of each having size 100 mb each

Tags: qgis, union

I have two shapefiles both are having polygon geometry, I am running Union process in QGIS using Vector/geoprocessing/union tool and It's taking weeks to process only 1 lac data, I don't know what's the problem with the software, I went through the same process several times but nothing fruitful found I also unchecked Rendering but no impact seems.
Can anyone suggest me, how can I speed up the process while running Union process?

I am using QGIS version 2.18.2.

if anyone on this group had faced the similar issues and got the solution Please help me it's very critical situation for me now.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the data, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: @RoVo The data is Parcel file having polygon rectangular shapes, while second file is also polygon file having flood information. I want to union both the file using QGIS. Please let me know if anything else you required.

Comment: Please update the question with this information. Also add information about the file format.

Comment: @RoVo updated the question, Please answer if you have.

Comment: Did you run the check validity tool to see if either layer has issues?  Are the layers in the same coordinate system? If not that may affect processing speed.  Can you run a union using the Grass GIS v.overlay tool in the processing toolbox.?

Comment: Thank you @johns. I got the desired result in very less time by running v.overlay in Grass GIS.